# Sidebar menu navigation in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to create a dashboard with sidebar menu. The menu would be changing the main container's content with calls to an external API. In sidebar, every click calls an action in Vuex store, where I call the backend, receive reply and store reply data and set a string according to which sidebar menu was clicked.
This string is then read by a computed function (setText) from the store to update the main container. In may examples I've only one component finished:

```
<div class="others">
       <div v-switch=setText>
          <div v-case="'show_sensors'"><Sensors :sensordata=localProperty :key="localProperty.id"/></div>
          <h1 v-case="'show_dashboard'">DASH</h1>
          <h2 v-case="'show_settings'">SETTINGS</h2>
          <h3 v-case="'show_log'">LOG</h3>
          <h1 v-case="'show_sites'">SITES</h1>
          <!-- <h2 v-case="'show_sensors'">SENSORS</h2> -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Localproperty is a computed function getting the stored reply from the API. By this way, I've got a working menu but in the console I'm getting error messages complaining that the sensordata props is undefined in case the user clicks on all menupoints except show_sensors.
([Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined).
It is obvious since the component cannot be initialized without its props. Although it is working I don't like the way that it generates error messages. Is there any workaround to solve this issue? Thanks!